# after entering < npm install --global expo-cli > in command line, version of expo didnot showed in terminal

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

the error appeared for me, I can't solve that even I don't know the meaning

[this is the screenshot of that block of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwFrG.png)